# How to a filter on the result on a stored procedure in DB2

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have a stored procedure in DB2 which returns a bunch of columns. I need to apply a 'WHERE' condition or do a sorting on one of the columns it returns. I don't want to touch the stored procedure and do this filtering/sorting when calling the stored procedure, something like below

```
select * from 'call SP1()' as T where T.column1 > 10
```

Is this possible in DB2?

Comment: Just make another stored-procedure that does the filtering, may be a wiser approach and simpler.

Comment: Consider using a User Defined Function that returns a table value. You can select from table UDFs (use `SELECT * FROM TABLE(YOUR_UDF())`  ) and UDFs can do many of the things that SPs can  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0003493.html   You can also call a SP in a UDF and PIPE() out the rows returned from the SP if you need https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0060687.html

Comment: Could you give me an example of PIPE() in an 'answer'?

Comment: OK. I was wrong with my second statement, a UDF can PIPE() out rows, but a UDF can't access the Result Sets from a SP, only the OUT or INOUT parameters. Sorry to get your hopes up.  So mao is right, wrap your SP in another SP. Otherwise, copy the code out from inside the SP and put it in a UDF.. depending on what the SP is doing, you may be able to do the same inside a table valued UDF

Comment: What I said immediately above is not true.. see answer below

Answer (score 1):

Here is a deliberately artificial example of a pipelined UDF that filters the result-set of an SQLPL procedure.

In real world coding, most programmers will avoid filtering outside of stored-procedures, simply because it is easier and better performing, and more natural to filter at the earliest possible opportunity.

Tested on Db2-LUW v11.1.3.3 and 11.1.2.2 with DB2_COMPATIBILITY_MODE=ORA (or at least Bit-17 set to 1 as in 0x10000 , acknowledgement to P.Vernon for this clarification):

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @

create or replace procedure alltabs
dynamic result sets 1
language sql
specific alltabs
begin
  declare v_cur cursor with return to caller for 
      select tabschema,tabname,type  from syscat.tables ;
  open v_cur;
end@


create or replace function allstatviews()
returns table (stat_view_name varchar(80))
begin
  declare v_rs result_set_locator varying;
  declare v_tabschema varchar(128);
  declare v_tabname   varchar(128);
  declare v_type      char(1);
  declare sqlstate char(5) default '00000';
  call alltabs;
  associate result set locator (v_rs) with procedure alltabs;
  allocate v_rscur cursor for result set v_rs;
  fetch from v_rscur into v_tabschema, v_tabname, v_type;
  while ( sqlstate = '00000') do
      if v_type='V' and v_tabschema='SYSSTAT'
      then
          pipe(cast(rtrim(v_tabschema)||'.'||rtrim( v_tabname) as varchar(80)));
      end if;
      fetch from v_rscur into v_tabschema, v_tabname, v_type;
  end while;
  return;
end@

select * from table(allstatviews())
@
```

Comment: Ah. Great to see that you can PIPE() a SP result set out of table UDF. I had a feeling it was possible, but when checking the KC it said it was not : "When a procedure is called within a trigger, compound statement, function, or method:   Result sets returned from the procedure cannot be accessed.".  Sometimes it is better to just _try it_

Comment: Actually, that code does not work for me on 11.1.3.3. I get `User‬‎ ‪defined‬‎ ‪routine ... ‪attempted‬‎ ‪to‬‎ ‪modify‬‎ ‪data‬‎ ‪but‬‎ ‪was‬‎ ‪not‬‎ ‪defined‬‎ ‪as‬‎ ‪MODIFIES‬‎ ‪SQL‬‎ ‪DATA‬‎...SQLCODE‬‎=‪‬‎-‪577‬‎‪‬‎`. If I add `MODIFIES‬‎ ‪SQL‬‎ ‪DATA‬‎` I then get `Multiple‬‎ ‪or‬‎ ‪conflicting‬‎ ‪keywords‬‎ ‪involving‬‎ ‪the‬‎ ‪‬‎"‪MODIFIES SQL DATA"‬‎ ‪clause‬‎ ‪are‬‎ ‪present‬‎.‪‬‎.‪‬‎ ‪SQLCODE‬‎=‪‬‎-‪628‬‎`

Comment: Works for me, but only on 11.1.3.3 (i.e. gives same symptom as you on 11.1.2.2). Assuming your fp3 mod3 is committed, try on a newly created database or run the relevant db2updv111* successfully against the database. Also failing that, show output of both db2set -all  and db2level in case your build level identifiers differ from mine ("0204010F")

Comment: Yes, only works with `db2set DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=ORA` and a db2stop/start. Well, specficially, if need bit 17 set on that vector `db2set DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=10000` https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/r0052867.html  which makes sense as that is "The degree to which a routine (stored procedure or user-defined function) can execute SQL statements"  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/c0057459.html   which explains why other parts of the manual says it not allowed...