# Call procedure from function and return the result

Tags: sql, function, db2, return, procedure

is it possible to call a procedure from a function and pass the result of that procedure as result of the function?

Like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION test()
return procedure
BEGIN
CALL TEST_PROC();
END@
```

And then call the function like

```
select * from table(test())@
```

and see the results of the procedure?

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: A piped SQL-function can return the result-set from an SQL-procedure (via the pipe statement) depending on your Db2-server platform , this works for Db2-for-Linux/Unix/Windows. There are documented restrictions and limitations. Choose a simpler design if you are a beginner, and do not over complicate.

Comment: could you give me an example?

Comment: What is your Db2-server operating-platform (Z/OS, i-series, LUW) and version?

Comment: Windows version 10.5

Comment: It might be useful to understand your end goal here. What are you trying to achieve with such functions as above and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52983941/function-with-different-returns-db2.  There may be better approaches to solve whatever problem or design issue you are facing

Comment: As previously mentioned, there are restrictions and limitations (one of them being that version 11.1.3.3 or higher is needed, along with ORA compatibility . See my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49923708/how-to-a-filter-on-the-result-on-a-stored-procedure-in-db2  . Consider a simpler design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend such an implementation, especially for large result sets.
But we can do such strange things in DB2 for LUW.

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
--
-- "SELECT FROM CALL" example.
-- Stored procedures are often defined as 'MODIFIES SQL DATA'.
-- A 'MODIFIES SQL DATA' table function in DB2 can be inlined only.
-- This means - no ability to process a procedure result set directly.
-- We must wrap the CALL to some intermediate procedure constructing an XML output with data processed.
-- 

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DESCRIBE_TABLE_XML(P_FULLTABNAME VARCHAR(256), OUT P_DOC XML)
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN 
  DECLARE SQLSTATE     CHAR(5);
  DECLARE L_NODE       XML;
  DECLARE L_COLNAME    VARCHAR(128);
  DECLARE L_TYPESCHEMA VARCHAR(128);
  DECLARE L_TYPENAME   VARCHAR(128);
  DECLARE L_LENGTH     INT;
  DECLARE L_SCALE      INT;
  DECLARE L_NULLS      CHAR(1);
  DECLARE V1           RESULT_SET_LOCATOR VARYING;

  CALL ADMIN_CMD('DESCRIBE TABLE '||P_FULLTABNAME);
  ASSOCIATE RESULT SET LOCATOR (V1) WITH PROCEDURE ADMIN_CMD;
  ALLOCATE C1 CURSOR FOR RESULT SET V1;

  SET P_DOC=XMLELEMENT(NAME "DOC");
  L1: LOOP
    FETCH C1 INTO L_COLNAME, L_TYPESCHEMA, L_TYPENAME, L_LENGTH, L_SCALE, L_NULLS;
    IF SQLSTATE<>'00000' THEN LEAVE L1; END IF;
    SET L_NODE=XMLELEMENT(NAME "NODE"
    , XMLELEMENT(NAME "COLNAME", L_COLNAME)
    , XMLELEMENT(NAME "TYPESCHEMA", L_TYPESCHEMA)
    , XMLELEMENT(NAME "TYPENAME", L_TYPENAME)
    , XMLELEMENT(NAME "LENGTH", L_LENGTH)
    , XMLELEMENT(NAME "SCALE", L_SCALE)
    , XMLELEMENT(NAME "NULLS", L_NULLS)
    );
    SET P_DOC=XMLQUERY(
      'transform copy $mydoc := $doc modify do insert $node as last into $mydoc return $mydoc'
      passing P_DOC as "doc", L_NODE as "node"
    );
  END LOOP L1;
  CLOSE c1;
END@

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DESCRIBE_TABLE_T(P_FULLTABNAME VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS TABLE (
  COLNAME    VARCHAR(128)
, TYPESCHEMA VARCHAR(128)
, TYPENAME   VARCHAR(128)
, LENGTH     INT
, SCALE      INT
, NULLS      CHAR(1)
)
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN ATOMIC
  DECLARE L_DOC XML;

  CALL DESCRIBE_TABLE_XML(P_FULLTABNAME, L_DOC);
  RETURN
  SELECT *
  FROM XMLTABLE ('$D/NODE' PASSING L_DOC AS "D" COLUMNS 
    COLNAME    VARCHAR(128) PATH 'COLNAME'
  , TYPESCHEMA VARCHAR(128) PATH 'TYPESCHEMA'
  , TYPENAME   VARCHAR(128) PATH 'TYPENAME'
  , LENGTH     INT          PATH 'LENGTH'
  , SCALE      INT          PATH 'SCALE'
  , NULLS      CHAR(1)      PATH 'NULLS'
  );
END@

SELECT * FROM TABLE(DESCRIBE_TABLE_T('SYSIBM.SYSTABLES'))@
SELECT * FROM TABLE(DESCRIBE_TABLE_T('SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS'))@
```